# How to deal with MultipleBagFetchException in JPA regarding multiple onetomany or manytomany relationship in JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relationship

I have following code

```
public class Product extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private List<Category> categories;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProductImage.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ProductImage> images;
    ...
}
```

As we can see one there were two relations and which shows the error of MultipleBagFetchException. One of them need to be removed.

Originally I am used to Laravel framework and newbie to springboot I have questions regarding relationship in Springboot JPA -

1. Is there any way to define relationship in entity class and load them only if required? For example of above code - do not load any relational data in list API but load all relational data (brand, categories, images) in detail API of the product.
2. Separate SQL query for each relation instead of join - I think joining multiple relation have Cartesian Product to merge multiple relational result which would be too costly.

Comment: MultipleBagFetchException problem has been solved for now using `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)`. I think its answer of Q1 but Q2 is still remaining.